# filling a gridview with combobox

Tags: vb.net, windows, gridview, combobox

I use combobox to filter a gridview, the gridview filtering occurs, but when i want to input a data in gridview in case that a grid have yet a lines (data), a message error displaying, so i cant enter a data, else when the grid have not at all data i can enter a value

the table behind gridview have an autogenerated field

```
Private Sub Le_clientComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Le_clientComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try

            Me.DevisBindingSource.Filter = "Code_client = '" & Le_clientComboBox.SelectedValue & "'"

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Finally
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                con.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub
```

the gridview is populated on load form

```
Private Sub frmDevis_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'TODO: cette ligne de code charge les données dans la table 'Tassaruf_tijariDataSet_Devis.Devis'. Vous pouvez la déplacer ou la supprimer selon vos besoins.
    Me.DevisTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Tassaruf_tijariDataSet_Devis.Devis)


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I respond my self

i think the problem is about filtering
i add remove filter, so it"s better, i can now input the data, but the grid doesn't work correctly! displaying one and unique line

```
 Private Sub Le_clientComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Le_clientComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        Me.DevisBindingSource.RemoveFilter()
        Me.DevisBindingSource.Filter = "Code_client = '" & Le_clientComboBox.SelectedValue & "'"

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```